# Xamarin.Android ReactiveUI With AppCompat?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-appcompat, reactiveui

Im getting the following error when trying to use SupportFragmentManager.

> SupportFragmentManager is not available in this context.

My Main Activity is extended to ReactiveActivity and I have installed

- reactiveui-androidsupport
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design

But I can not use the SupportFragmentManager.
How to implement this correctly with Xamarin.Android + ReactiveUI?

**Code Segment:**

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
                    break;
            }

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
                .Commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend from `ReactiveAppCompatActivity` in the [ReactiveUI.AndroidSupport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.AndroidSupport/8.0.0-alpha0113)  package. That one extends from `AppCompatActivity` which provides access to `SupportFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0):

The  `ReactiveActivity` doesn't extend [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) from the support library, therefore you can't use the `SupportFragmentManager`.

If you are targeting api 11 or above, you could use `Activity.FragmentManager` instead. If you use `Activity.FragmentManager` your `Fragment` type need change to `Android.App.Fragment`.